# Can we copy .BAK(SQL Server Backup Files) files from on-premise server file folder to Azure Blob Storage using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: filesystems, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, database-backups, on-premises-instances

I have some SQL server backup files on my **on-premise server** on the **D:\AzureTesting*** folder and I want to copy those .bak files from there to my **Azure Blob Storage Account** using Azure Data Factory?
Is it feasible if so, please let me know how to proceed with?
I have searched a lot on the web, but I am not getting an appropriate method for this.
I tried to load using Copy activity taking File System Linked Service as my source it is showing me only the below file formats to choose from.
[See the Image Link for the file formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UvB5.png)
Can anyone suggest which file format should I select for accepting the. bak files from my on-premise to Azure Blob storage
An answer or any kind of solution is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to copy it via copy activity.
For the on prem server, you would have to install an integration run time and create a linked server of type: file system and the destination would be azure blob storage.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Nandan for your quick response ,I will try as per said. Hope it will fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Hey @NehaKumari,
you can also refer the below link for detailed steps:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5928/transfer-onpremises-files-to-azure-blob-storage/
of setting IR and creating copy activity.

Please mark it as answer in case if it helped as it may benefit other community members

Comment: Hey @Nandan while choosing File System as Linked Service,it is showing me only these file formats (Avro format, Binary format,Delimited text format,JSON format,ORC format,Parquet format) to choose from . Can you suggest which file format should I select for accepting .bak files

Comment: Hey @nehakumari, you use binary format across source and destination to copy a file as is

Comment: Hey @Nandan ,Are you sure because I have tried using the binary file format as source and sink but it gave me the following error:
Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=AdlsGen2OperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'. Account: 'medinsightsandbox'. FileSystem: 'uaw'. Path: 'dm_test/KumarP/Bak_File_Storage/TestFile.bak'. ErrorCode: 'AuthorizationFailure'. Message: 'This request is not authorized to perform this operation.'. .

Comment: Message: 'This request is not authorized to perform this operation.'. RequestId: '468f2a81-f01f-0039-55ba-098ac1000000'. TimeStamp: 'Tue, 23 Feb 2021 08:05:55 GMT'..,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden',Source=,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.Models.ErrorSchemaException,Message=Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

Comment: Hey @NehaKumari,
Can you please test whether your file systme linked server connection was successful?
Based on the error, it seems that the account doenst have access on that path in the VM